# How to create an auto increment field for a django model, with two keys which are unique_together?

Tags: django, unique, atomic

I have a model like

```
class Item(models.Model):
    site = Site()
    id_on_site = PositiveIntegerField()
```

Now i want to create an instance `Item(current_site, next_id_on_site)` with

```
next_id_on_site = Item.objects.filter(site=current_site).aggregate(current_id=Max("id_on_site"))['current_id']+1
```

The problem is, that the operation of generating the ID and creating the `Item` is not atomic, so there is a race condition which creates duplicate IDs, so `.get(site=current_site, id_on_site=someid)` will raise a `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception.

Using `unique_together` in the model does not help with the generation of the auto increment ID and doesn't seem to be implemented at the DB level at all.

Comment: id_on_site is auto generating id ?

Answer (score 2):

`unique_together` is definitely implemented in the database, but since it generates a unique database index, you may need to run a migration to see its effects.

If *all* you want is for `id_on_site` to be some unique identifier for the item at the site, it might be easier to use something like a `UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)`, which has a near-certain guarantee of uniqueness. If you need the ID to be an auto-incrementing integer, that's a bit harder.

One option to avoid the race condition would be to lock the row with the highest `id_on_site` value. (This will only work on [certain database backends,](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) e.g. postgres):

```
from django.db.transaction import atomic

with atomic():
    next_id_on_site = (
        Item.objects
        .filter(site=current_site)
        .select_for_update(nowait=False)
        .latest('id_on_site').id_on_site)
    Item.objects.create(current_site, next_id_on_site)
```

This should cause other transactions to block if they're trying to get the highest `id_on_site`, and once the transaction is committed, the item you just inserted will be returned to the other transaction. This could be problematic if the transaction is long-lived for some reason.

Comment: I want to use incrementing integers, as this are numbers i want to show to the users of the site. I tried with atomic, but i think it does not work with mysql. My current try is to save the item with invalid id, then aggregative the maximum id and run ``Item.objects.filter(id=newitem.id).update(id_on_site=new_id)``, which runs faster than ``item.save()``, but this still causes race conditions between the aggregate and the update. The docs look like ``select_for_update`` should work for mysql even when it does not have as nice transactions like postres. I will try it.

Comment: Atomic works for both database backends, but wouldn't solve the race condition. If the locking approach doesn't work, it might be worth writing a raw SQL query to update the row. It should be a simple SQL statement, just one that's hard to express in Django's ORM.

Comment: I think for the updating, the ``.filter(...).update(...)`` line just creates a single ``UPDATE ... WHERE ...`` statement.

Comment: docs looks like (my)sql "SELECT ... FOR UPDATE" just locks the selected rows. I do not see if it locks for aggregation involving this row as well. Possibly it will need a full table lock to be 100% effective.